# Captain Scarlet and the Mysterons radio stalk activation

Tags: captain-scarlet

I was recently on a radio protocol training course, this was to get all using the same procedure when communicating with overhead crane operators. As part of this we were wearing headsets with a microphone on a stalk. I was attending with a lifelong friend and I mentioned how Captain Scarlet had one built into his hat back when we were schoolboys and watched the series.

He remembered how it used to slide down into position when the Captain was to speak on the radio and then go back up to the peak of his cap. "Ah yes" said I, "the pulse in - pulse out activating"

Blank look from my friend, I explained how the Captain twisted his wrist inwards while driving the Spectrum Pursuit Vehicle, this brought the microphone down, after the radio talk he twisted his wrist outwards and the microphone returned up on his hat peak.

My colleague couldn't remember this action so I've since then looked on Google and Wikipedia and a couple of Gerry Anderson sites but no mention did I find of 'Pulse In - Pulse Out'

Have I had my own personal Mandela Effect moment with this? Am I the only person who thinks this happened?

Update: I've looked at my question again this morning and it's just possible that I might not have seen this on television. I might have instead read it in the Captain Scarlet strip in TV21, I got this every week while the series was on the air

Comment: The radio piece seems to flip down automatically; https://youtu.be/MEQ_ViylodU?t=296 and https://youtu.be/MEQ_ViylodU?t=944

Comment: I recall it coming down automatically for incoming calls from HQ but how did it work when a Spectrum agent decided he needed to make an outgoing call?

Comment: As far as I can remember, it just flips down on its own when an outgoing call needs to be made.

Comment: I mentioned it might have been something I read in the CS comic strip but someone suggested on another site that it may have been a feature on a Captain Scarlet action figure (similar to eagle eye action man) . I never owned one but some of my friends did ...fifty plus years ago so faded memories!

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look through [the Spectrum Agents' Manual](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Captain-Scarlet-Manual-Haynes-Manuals/dp/1785211439), but all I can find there is

> An integral part of the officers' uniform and the Angels' flying suits are the high powered transmitter/receivers respectively built into the officers' caps and the Angels' helmets. These allow the users to make direct contact with operatives and with Colonel White at his control desk.

It doesn't go into any further detail about how they actually work beyond that.